# WordPress theme creation : There are no widget areas on the page shown

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and i am creating a theme from scratch.
I want to create a widget area, but the customize panel always tells :

*There are no widget areas on the page shown, however other pages in this theme do have them*

How do you guys create a widget area ? Could you please tell me what do I need to put in my files ?

Thank you

Comment: Refer this link hope this will help you, http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

Comment: Thank you for your link, but it does not tell me how do I setup a widget area, it explains how to create a widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Registering Widget In Wordpress:

Add this code Into your theme functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_slug_widgets_init' );
function theme_slug_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'theme-slug' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Widgets in this area will be shown on all posts and pages.', 'theme-slug' ),
        'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '',
    'after_title'   => '',
    ) );
}
```

Instead of `theme_slug_` you should use your own theme slug. Also you can check this page for more information.

After Registering Widget Write in Any Custom Template Or where you want to display that Widget:

```
<?php get_sidebar('Main Sidebar'); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but does not work for me. I just created a child theme, using as "parent" a fully functionnal theme with a working widget area, but as soon as I "override" the parent theme by adding a header.php, index.php, or footer.php in my child theme folder, the widget area disapears and I it displays : "There are no widget areas on the page shown, however other pages in this theme do have them"

Comment: Are you sure that you created your child theme correctly? You should put `Template: your parent theme` in comment section of your child theme style.css file.

Comment: Yes I did. When I customize my child theme while nothing overrides it, it displays exactly like the parent theme.

Comment: Everything looks correct. Override the files one by one to see when the widget disappeared. Then check the file. Maybe there is a code for removing widget areas on that!

Comment: I just did that, and I found out why I couldnt had any widgets : I had to put the `get_sidebar()` in the header.php and not the index.php, and I also had to add `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`. No tutorials told me to do that, I had to try blindly. I dont know if it is the right way to do it but it does work fine now.

Comment: Happy to see that you fixed the problem finally :) off course if the widget location is in the header, then you should place it in header.php file.

Comment: Thank you for your time Hossein. I am used to "classic" php and sql development, but I feel lost with WordPress! Maybe we'll meet again in another WordPress topic o/

Comment: Your welcome. I suggest to check a started WP theme as a sample to get more familiar with WP structure :)